# Sending gmail from web server

Tags: python, smtp, webserver

In my python file I am sending mail from gmail:

I used 
`server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)`
I am successfully sending mails from my local system,

I executed same code in the web server I got this error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.4/smtplib.py", line 244, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.4/smtplib.py", line 306, in connect
        raise socket.error, msg
    socket.error: (97, 'Address family not supported by protocol')
```

How to send mails using gmail in web server using python?

Answer (score -1):

Try SMTP_SSL, based on the below it'll probably help:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html